# Azure Storage Table Query - result vs response

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage

I'm using node.js as my Server and have an account on Azure where my storage table resides. I'm retrieving all records for a specific partition by using the following :

```
var query= new azure.TableQuery().where('PartitionKey eq ?',username);
tableSvc.queryEntities(localTableName,query, null, function(error, result, response) {
```

}

When this call comes back, I want to access the values for the rest of the fields of table. But when I do that using result.entries, it kinda looks weird. Alternatively I think I can access the results via response.body.value.userID.

Here is how the structure of "result.entries" vs "response" object looks like:

```
    result.entries :
    [ { PartitionKey: { '$': 'Edm.String', _: '048tfbne' },
        RowKey: { '$': 'Edm.String', _: '145610564488450166' },
        Timestamp: 
               { '$': 'Edm.DateTime',
                   _: Mon Feb 22 2016 01:47:26 GMT+0000 (UTC) },
        username: { _: '048tfbne' },
        userID: { _: '145610564488450166' },
        deleteAfter: { _: 'not set yet' },
        '.metadata': { etag: 'W/"datetime\'2016-02-22T01%3A47%3A26.4394133Z\'"' } } ]

    response : 
    { isSuccessful: true,
        statusCode: 200,
              body: 
                { 'odata.metadata': 'https://photoshareuserdata.table.core.windows.net/$metadata#userIdentifier',
                value: 
                    [ { 'odata.etag': 'W/"datetime\'2016-02-22T01%3A47%3A26.4394133Z\'"',
                        PartitionKey: '048tfbne',
                        RowKey: '145610564488450166',
                        Timestamp: '2016-02-22T01:47:26.4394133Z',
                        username: '048tfbne',
                        userID: '145610564488450166',
                        deleteAfter: 'not set yet' } ] },
```

I thought results.entries would be a better way to access the records, but I am sort of weirded out by the nested objects and Edm.String here.

Which is a better way to access the records ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Table Node Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-table-node-getting-started/blob/master/tableSample.js) shows how to access entities in a table as result of a query. See method "runPageQuery".

Comment: Thank you! That looks promising, I'll try that and report back.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, according the official [Section: Query a set of entities](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-table-storage/#query-a-set-of-entities), there is a paragraph as following:

> If successful, **result.entries** will contain an array of entities that match the query. If the query was unable to return all entities, **result.continuationToken** will be non-null and can be used as the third parameter of queryEntities to retrieve more results.

And we also can refer to the [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/examples/samples/tablequerysample.js#L94) at Azure-storage-for-node repository on GitHub. Which has told us the answer.

Comment: Thanks Gary.

The documentation looks good, I have changing my code yet. I will update once I get back around to trying it out.